# What is the difference between default_value and implicit_value in boost::program_options?

Tags: boost, boost-program-options

That's the question.  Why would I use implicit_value over default_value and vice versa?

Thanks!

Answer (score 44):

[`default_value()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost/program_options/typed_value.html#id887008-bb) is the value that will be put in the [`variables_map`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost/program_options/variables_map.html) if the user didn't specify another value:

```
./a.out             # implies width=75 if that's the default_value for width
./a.out --width=80  # default_value not used
```

[`implicit_value()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost/program_options/typed_value.html#id887054-bb) is the value that will be used if the user specifies the option but without an adjacent value.

```
./a.out --width     # implies width=75 if that's the implicit_value for width
./a.out --width=80  # implicit value not used
```

If you use `implicit_value` then in commandline options's short options the user must specify the value immediately after the option:

```
./a.out -w80   # implicit_value not used
./a.out -w 80  # wrong: 80 parsed as extra arg if implicit_value is defined
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an [example](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/boost/+/077d563efdb280a3d144892e2d0ca01e6a49f454/libs/program_options/example/options_description.cpp)

```
    desc.add_options()
        ("help", "produce help message")
        ("optimization", po::value<int>(&opt)->default_value(10), 
              "optimization level")
        ("verbose,v", po::value<int>()->implicit_value(1),
              "enable verbosity (optionally specify level)")
        ("listen,l", po::value<int>(&portnum)->implicit_value(1001)
              ->default_value(0,"no"),
              "listen on a port.")
        ("include-path,I", po::value< vector<string> >(), 
              "include path")
        ("input-file", po::value< vector<string> >(), "input file")
    ;
```

If you don't input either optimization or listen,

> ./myApp.exe

output:

```
 Optimization level is 10
 Listen port is 0
```

If you input option `--optimization` without an argument, it will nofity missing argument. And if you input `--listen` without an argument, it will give an implicit value 1001.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember right, the difference arises with an option that allows something like `-X=Y` (where "Y" might be, for example, a number). The default value is what you get if the user hasn't entered a `-X` on the command line. An implicit value is is what you get if the user enters `-X` on the command line without specifying a value.

Consider, for example, gcc, which supports optimization levels from 0 to 3 (IIRC). If you don't specify `-O` at all, it defaults to `-O0` (i.e., optimization is turned off). If you specify `-O` (with no number) you get the implicit value, equivalent to `-O1`. You can also specify `-O1` explicitly, or you can specify `-O2` or `-O3`.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily reflect on what the user specified on the commandline. Boost's program_options uses `options_descriptor` for all its parsers, so if for example the value is specified in a configuration file or an environment-variable then the library won't fallback to the `default_value`.